# How do I self-sign a Certificate Signing Request in C#? Bouncy Castle ok

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, self-signed, csr

I don't need to generate the certificate signing request.  I just need to self-sign it for testing purposes.

I have the gotten the CSR stored into a Pkcs10CertificationRequest variable.  Is it pretty simple from there?  I'm new to the self-signing game... help!

Working code to get decoded CSR:

```
var decodedCsr = (Pkcs10CertificationRequest)(
                new Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemReader(
                new StringReader(csr.csr)).ReadObject());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a self-signed certificate using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806299/how-can-i-create-a-self-signed-certificate-using-c)

Comment: Not really, unless I'm on the wrong path here.  I already have the certificate request.  I do not need to create it.  I just need the self-signing part.

Comment: If you have requested a certificate, then you must wait for them to sign it. If you want a self signed certificate, create it yourself and self sign it.

Comment: I'm being sent a certificate request.  I'm not requesting it.

Comment: Then you're not self-signing it. Self-signing means the private key you use to sign the certificate is the keypair mate of the public key that is in the certificate. In short, you signed your own public key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signing CSR using Bouncy Castle in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046446/signing-csr-using-bouncy-castle-in-c-sharp)